# email piping doesn't work , no error ! email doesn't bounce back

Tags: php, email

Here is my email forwarding

[image]

Here is my pipe.php with 777 permission

[image]

Here is the code of `pipe.php`:

```
   #!/usr/bin/php -q
    <?php 
    @mail('myemail@gmail.com','From my email pipe!','done done done 3');
    ?>
```

But when I send email to `help@email.jonoobhost.net` nothing happens ! not even `could not be delivered` message !

Am I missing something ?

```
Incoming Server:    server.hhost.com

    IMAP Port: 993
    POP3 Port: 995

Outgoing Server:    server.hhost.com

    SMTP Port: 465
```

Comment: What email server are you using?

Comment: Does the script have execute permission set?

Comment: @IvanNevostruev i've added some info at the end of my question

Comment: @Barmar i've set it to 777

Comment: I was asking about software running on your email server. Not all email servers have "Pipe to a program" functionality.

Comment: @IvanNevostruev i've to ask support about that , can't i find that out from my cpanel ?!

Comment: Would the server have that option in the user portal if it didn't actually support it? Anyway, you should probably ask the hosting provider to check the logs and see what happened to the mail.

Comment: @Barmar maybe it came with cpanel !

Comment: Also please post content of `pipe.php`.

Comment: @IvanNevostruev i've already did , under the last image

Comment: I see. Then I don't understand what do yo expect to happen here? Can you please give more details on that?

Comment: @IvanNevostruev i expect to receive a email  after sending one to that address ,as you can see from pipe.php code

Comment: Do you have ssh access to server? Can you run your `pipe.php` script from command line and check if it works as expected?

Comment: @IvanNevostruev not right now , but that can be arranged ... but it works fine when i run it from browser ... i get the email as expected so i belive script is fine

Comment: I think you should talk to your hosting provider. Because it's very hard for us to guess what it wrong here, without having access to your system. Most likely problem is related to provider specific functionality. As @Barmar suggested you can also look in logs. I suggest to remove `@` from `@mail(...)`. So you'll see errors if there are any. Also you can try to write to log (for example with `file_put_contents('/tmp/pipe.log', 'called')`).